# Why we need to pass module.exports as a parameter since we are already passing module as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, require

I have been going through some online tutorials on Node.js. What I understood is that, on using `require(./file-path)` function, the node gets the content of that file and wraps inside an immediately invoking function

```
(function(exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {
  // content 
}())
```

I understood the difference between `exports` and `module.exports`. That's all I can see in the internet on searching the above question. But what my question is , why we need to pass `module.exports` and `module` to the wrapping IIFE? We could have passed module alone and then get `module.exports` from it. Is there any advantage on doing like this? Normally when we pass an object to a function , we don't have to pass `object.property` additionally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is: historical reasons.

You're right, we could have only `module` and `exports` would not be needed but it's still there for backwards compatibility.

It used to be a time when the module wrapper was changed in pretty much every patch release.

In Node 0.1.11 the module wrapper was:

```
var wrapper = "function (__filename) { "+
              "  var onLoad; "+
              "  var onExit; "+
              "  var exports = this; "+
              content+
              "\n"+
              "  this.__onLoad = onLoad;\n"+
              "  this.__onExit = onExit;\n"+
              "};\n";
```

See: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v0.1.11/src/node.js#L167#L177

As you can see the `exports` was the same as the `this` that the wrapper function was called with. You couldn't swap it with a new object and you couldn't even add some reserved keys to it - e.g. you couldn't safely export a property named `__onExit`.

Then in 0.1.12 it was:

```
var wrapper = "function (__filename, exports) { " + content + "\n};";
```

See: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v0.1.12/src/node.js#L243-L245

Here the `exports` was an object supplied as one of the arguments but you couldn't swap it with a new object, you could only add or remove properties from the object that you got.

Then the 0.1.13 was the first to have this, i.e. `require` and `include`:

```
var wrapper = "function (__filename, exports, require, include) { " + content + "\n};";
```

See: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v0.1.13/src/node.js#L225-L227

Then 0.1.14 was the first to have `__module` (with underscores) in the wrapper (and that dropped `include`):

```
var wrapper = "var __wrap__ = function (__module, __filename, exports, require) { " 
            + content 
            + "\n}; __wrap__;";
```

See: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v0.1.14/src/node.js#L280-L284

And the 0.1.16 was the first to have a `module` argument (with no underscores) in the wrapper:

```
var wrapper = "var __wrap__ = function (exports, require, module, __filename) { " 
            + content 
            + "\n}; __wrap__;";
```

See: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v0.1.16/src/node.js#L444-L448

It's been changed many times after that but this is the time that the `module` got introduced making the `exports` not necessary any more but still a useful shortcut, allowing you to use:

```
exports.a = 1;
exports.b = 2;
exports.c = 3;
```

instead of:

```
module.exports.a = 1;
module.exports.b = 2;
module.exports.c = 3;
```

though in practice if there was no `exports` then one would usually write:

```
const exports = module.exports;
exports.a = 1;
exports.b = 2;
exports.c = 3;
```

or more likely:

```
module.exports = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: 3,
};
```

or, to have some checks in static analysis tools:

```
const a = 1;
const b = 2;
const c = 3;
module.exports = { a, b, c };
```

There are many ways to do it, it's a pretty flexible mechanism.

Comment: Beat me to it. Was earlier than I remembered.

Answer (score 2):

Originally it was only `exports` and `require`.
Later on, `module` was added in a backwards-compatible manner, to allow (among other things) overriding the exports object completely.

Comment: Let me see if I can find the change. I think it's somewhere around v0.6.

Comment: Later when they added module, why didn't they remove module.exports then ? They can get it anyway from module object.

Comment: @MELWINVINCENT because that would have broken both old modules using the new platform, and new modules using the old platform.